# Cohomology of a smooth quadric

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Q$ be a smooth quadric of dimension $l$. A statement that I keep coming across, and which annoyingly always comes with "it is well known that" in front of it, is the following: $H^k(Q)=0$ when $k$ is odd, $H^{2i}(Q)=\mathbb{Q}(-i)$ when $1 \leq i \leq l$, unless the dimension is even $l=2k$ in which case $H^{2k}(Q) = \mathbb{Q}(-k) \oplus \mathbb{Q}(-k)$.

The proof should involve the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, Gysin maps etc. but I have never been able to complete it myself, and I have never found a clear reference for it, so any of these (proof or reference) would be a great help.

Comment: You can find a proof not using Schubert calculus in Miles Reid's thesis, "The complete intersection of two or more quadrics", pages 32-33.

Answer (score 1):

A smooth projective quadric is a homogeneous variety of a simple algebraic group, consequently it has an algebraic cellular decomposition (by Schubert cells), whose combinatorics can be read of from the Weyl group.